# Multiple group name with for each @section using rtf template

Tags: xml, rtf, bi-publisher

I have an rtf template and the user's requirement is to print a batch of documents based on the transaction number.

Now to do this, I search something in Google and I found the  function.

I tried the above function and it works in my header and footer potion, however, my problem is the data from the other group_name is not showing and return as blank.

I've attached the sample rtf template and xml file for your reference.

[Sample XML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hM-CjwKsM316yGb8Ly9u51Y-sffxKYCv/view?usp=sharing)

[Sample RTF](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o031TtJMBT4mVqdcFidjLXln6PAACXjM/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114084192057052663535&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Thank you,
Lawrence

Comment: I would edit the sample RTF file to add the missing group names manually.  Once you modify the sample RTF you should be able to use the existing functions to access the cells of the RTF.

Comment: Hi, yes, please. It would be a big help if the missing group names will appear in this template. Thank you, Lawrence

Comment: Please show example output that you want, and example that you are getting.